# matlab: find circles

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new to matlab!
I'm trying to detect pupils from a frame sequence... I need to use this approach to detect whether eyes are open or not.

imfindcircles is working when I don't use erode and dilate, but that steps of erode and dilate are bringing me a really cool image, it's a very clean black circle on white background, Hough will work like a charm, but it doesn't and I cannot really find a way out.
It doesn't depend on radii range, because if I comment erode and dilate it works. Erode and dilate produce a perfect image as I just said.

Any tips?

```
rightEye = imcrop(videoFrame, rightEyeBox);
leftEye = imcrop(videoFrame, leftEyeBox);

% to grayscale
grayRightEye = rgb2gray(rightEye);
grayLeftEye = rgb2gray(leftEye);

% binarize
grayRightEye = im2bw(grayRightEye, 0.45);

% erode and dilate
finalRight = imdilate(grayRightEye, strel('disk', 7));
finalRight = imerode(finalRight, strel('disk', 11));

imshow(grayRightEye);

rightCircle = max(rightRows, rightCols);
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(grayRightEye,[5 25])
```

Comment: Is this the only algo you can use? For eye-blink detection there are other relatively effective and simple algos aswell!

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506393/how-to-detect-pupil-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by typecasting finalRight to double!